# How to pass database connection sting to NUnit runner on TeamCity?

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I have a `TeamCity` with 3 agents, and more that 20 configurations for different branches.
Simultaneously on `TeamCity` runs multiple builds what use same 2-3 databases for unit tests. But in each branches this databases has a differences: new table, columns, etc.

In Db project in c# i have `recreate database` option.
I think errors occurs because database hardcoded in app.config of test project and when new build runs its recreate database.
So how i see that solution is create database for each configuratons and runs tests on it.
How can i pass connections string to unit tests runner, and if possible autogenerate it?

Also i got a little sugegstion that error occurs couse `*.edmx` files what generated on agents and never removes.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [build parameters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-build-parameters.html#ConfiguringBuildParameters-UsingBuildParametersintheBuildScripts) for specifying the connection string.

As about the possibility to generate a connection string, you can do it with [pre-defined parameters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html#PredefinedBuildParameters-ServerBuildProperties) (e.g., take a build configuration name from it or project name).

Didn't you think about using docker for databases?